# Bootstrap navigation bar active state

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

- I have a website with a common heading.
- That heading is included a navigation bar.
- When I click a navigation item in the bar page load happens.
- Considering the context how can I set the Bootstrap navigation bar active state for navigation item which is related to the loaded page.

Since there is a page load when clicking on a navigation bar item, I cannot just use

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Please provide me a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is loaded you have to check if the links of the anchors match with the page location.

```
$(".nav a").each(function() {
  if(document.location.href.indexOf(this.href)>=0) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for my issue, I followed the following way.

I added HTML IDs for each of my navigation bar items.
Then in each page related to each navigation bar item, I added Bootstrap active class using javascript as follows.

$("#ID_of_the_navi_bar_item").addClass('active');